# How to convert old MS Word documents to plain text?

Tags: php, apache, text, ms-word

I want to get textual content from MSword 03 or older versions. Is there a script or software package that can do this?

I am able to get text out of word files for 2007 documents. I am not able to get the same from  older versions (.doc).

I am using apache2 and php mysql.

Comment: how do you get text out of word 2007 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PHP class for ms word documents at http://obninsk.name/obninsk_doc/ .

Comment: Hi Shiven, I am getting this error after runnig that PHP class..Debug Error: C:\xampp\htdocs\mgh\obninsk_doc.php line 100 - Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)

Please let me know what to do..!!!

Comment: try searching  if this statement exists
ini_set('memory_limit', '33M');
then change it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try `catdoc`, which converts any .doc file into plain text. See the [catdoc homepage](http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use LiveDocx which handles all MS Word Files including RTF http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/08/13/convert-docx-doc-rtf-to-html-in-php/